# Which PgBackRest policy for differential backups in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, backup, recovery, disk-space, tools

I set up pgBackRest and PostgreSQL configuration in two different servers.

I set up with crontab one full backup a week and one differential backup a day.

```
0  1   *   *   0     pgbackrest --type=full --stanza=stanzaname backup  
0  1   *   *   1-6   pgbackrest --type=diff --stanza=stanzaname backup
```

I set up retention as below to save disk usage:

```
repo1-retention-full=2  
repo1-retention-diff=1
repo1-retention-archive-type=full
```

Is it possible to ensure PITR to cover up to 2 weeks with this retention configuration?

If yes, is there a benefit to set a differential retention more than 1?
Because keeping more differential backups could consume a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your archive (WAL) retention policy, maybe.

1. Nightly diffs: Relying solely on your nightly differential, your PITR recovery window would only go as far as last Sunday's full backup. From their docs, "Differential Backup: pgBackRest copies only those database cluster files that have changed since the **last full backup**".

   Let's say today it's Thursday Sept 19th, and that you want to recover up to last week's Tuesday (the 10th). You can't use your only differential, the one taken tonight (the 19th) at 1am, which only contains changes since the last full backup take on Sunday the 15th. If you restore your oldest full backup, the one taken on Sunday 8th, you have no differentials taken from Monday 9th until Sat 14th to apply to it.
2. WAL archives: So, can you use archived WAL files then, if you apply them after restoring the full backup taken on Sunday Sept 8th? Maybe - this is the part where I think the documentation is a bit unclear: "pgBackRest automatically removes archived WAL segments when expiring backups (the default expires WAL for full backups based on the repo1-retention-full option)".

   I am not sure if they mean that last week's WALS are kept around or not; sounds like maybe yes, since the oldest full is not expired yet.. but the statement in brackets gives me some pause.
3. Regardless of #2, my recommendation would be to find a solution that doesn't rely solely on WAL archive retention. You may either configure a higher retention for your nightly diffs so you don't need to rely solely on WAL archives (ideal but heavy on disk usage), or only do a full backup every 2 weeks (I don't like this option myself, since I prefer the peace of mind of a weekly full)

   Or you can do what we do, **nightly incrementals**: "Incremental backups cannot be expired independently — they are always expired with their related full or differential backup."

   To achieve the same PITR window of 14 days we are doing:

   - Sat 1am full backups, retention 2
   - Nightly **incrementals** from Sun-Fri

We find the above to be a good balance for us: the nightly incrementals are relatively small and are quicker than a differential, especially as we get farther from the Saturday full.

*Source: https://pgbackrest.org/user-guide.html (visited in 2019-09-19)*

Comment: The benefit in using differentials backups is the time to restore.
If you restore from the last full backup you have to replay all wal files (xlog, redo logs) from the last full backup to your point to restore.
If you have some differentials backups between the fulls backups, you need less wal files and the time to restore is shorter.

Comment: I understand. It's about striking a balance that works for you. In our case, since we expect we will be *creating* backups say 99% of the time, vs 1% of the time *restoring* them, we prefer to focus on creating them efficiently. 

You of course will be dealing with your own restore time targets, in which case having the fastest restore possible will be useful, for sure.

One thing that impacts performance that I did not mention: we use the fastest compression level -- the resulting disk usage is only about 10% higher, with much speedier backup times.

Comment: An update on my last comment regarding compression: PGBackRest now supports additional compression algorithms. We've experimented with some, and this is what we currently use: When we need to minimize backup sizes and don't care about performance: bzip2 maximum level. When bzip2 is taking so long that it is still running when we want the system to be as unloaded as possible for the daily data-heavy processes: zstd at the default level. zstd in our experience is about as "compressy" as gzip, but quite faster. bzip2 at max level is ~2x as efficient as zstd, but ~6x slower ime.